# “muito” + singular countable noun, “muitos” + plural countable noun — are they both correct?

Tags: significado, número-gramatical

Consider the following sentences in the spoken language:

- "Tem muito estudante que se considera despreparado para o mercado de trabalho"
- "Temos muitos estudantes inscritos para as vagas de estagiário."
- "Tem muito professor que nem se preocupa com o aprendizado...."
- "Tem muitos professores que nunca participaram de uma greve."

I've often heard both kinds in pt-BR but I'm not sure whether “muito” + singular countable noun is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a curious construction in that it uses singular with plural meaning. So the following pairs mean the same:

> *ainda **morre muita criança** de fome nos dias de hoje* = *ainda **morrem muitas crianças** de fome* nos dias de hoje
>
> *apanhei **muita bebedeira valente** na minha juventude* = *apanhei **muitas bebedeiras valentes** na minha juventude*

This construction is ubiquitous and readily-understood in both spoken and written language across all, as far as I know, Portuguese-speaking world, and definitely in Portugal and Brazil. And it has been used by our greatest writers for over three centuries. You can’t get more correct than that.

Here are a few examples, starting with the earliest example I could find (emphasis mine, in all quotes):

> **Muito livrinho** dourado e enfeitado vejo eu lá por essa banda. [[Francisco Manuel de Melo, *O hospital das letras*, 1657.]](https://archive.org/stream/apologosdialogae00mell/apologosdialogae00mell_djvu.txt)
>
> ALGODOEIRO. Planta, que dà Algodaõ. […] Dà **muita flor** fermosa grande da feição de huma campainha fendida em cinco, ou seis quartos atè a base de cor amarella, misturada com vermelho, ou purpureo. [[Rafael Bluteau, *Vocabulário portuguez e latino*, 1712-21]](http://purl.pt/13969/4/l-2771-a/l-2771-a_item4/l-2771-a_PDF/l-2771-a_PDF_24-C-R0090/l-2771-a_0000_capa-capa_t24-C-R0090.pdf)
>
> Verá Vossa Mercê **muita obra** nova em Lisboa, e algumas que lhe não desagradarão; [[Cartas de Alexandre Gusmão, 1735.]](http://www.tycho.iel.unicamp.br/corpus/cgi-bin/getversion.pl)
>
> Lá por Lisboa e por o Porto ha **muita menina** galante, isso ha; muita inglezinha loira, bonitas como anjos, mas cabelos assim doirados? [[Júlio Diniz, *Morgadinha dos Canaviais*, 1868]](https://pt.wikisource.org/wiki/P%C3%A1gina:A_morgadinha_dos_canaviais.djvu/116)
>
> Teria poupado muita aflição e **muita lágrima**, a si e aos seus, se tomasse antes o caminho direito, que é sempre o melhor. [[Machado de Assis, *Helena*, 1876.]](http://sanderlei.com.br/JP/Machado/Machado-de-Assis-07/Helena-24)
>
> mas a verdade é que fechada a noite, escapava **muita mulher e muito menino**, que os homens faziam sair na escuridão, por veredas escondidas. [[Rachel de Queiroz, *Dôra, Doralina*, 1975.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=cp8qAQAAIAAJ&q=%22escapava%20muita%20mulher%20e%20muito%20menino%22&dq=%22escapava%20muita%20mulher%20e%20muito%20menino%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj_3v2wkoLOAhWDORoKHd1ID9QQ6AEIHTAA)
>
> Acho que era natural ainda que um fidalgo achasse uma afronta mortal isto da mulher andar a dormir com um moço, mesmo da confiança, que é uma coisa que ainda hoje deixa **muito homem** perturbado. [António Alçada Batista, *Os Nós e os Laços*, 1985.]

I didn’t find this construction discussed in any modern grammar or dictionary, but [António Morais da Silva (1755-1824)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant%C3%B3nio_de_Morais_Silva), the greatest lexicographer of the Portuguese language of his time, approved of it in his [1813 *Diccionario da Lingua Portugueza* (entry *advérbio*):](https://books.google.pt/books?id=u89FAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22diriamos%20alias%20certo&source=bl&ots=JU9HJRk_44&sig=RoPIaPoNcuz5kARa0RIO914y8C0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjz5qLBloLOAhWCoRoKHWPMBVEQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=%22diriamos%20alias%20certo&f=false)

> Então se modificão os nomes usados attributivamente , não concordão com o nome , que parecem modificar , e assim dizemos bem : *v.g.* “isso não é *mũito mentira* ;” e não *mũita* , salvo quando *mũita* se refere a numero : *v.g.* dice-lhe *mũita mentira* , por *muitas. Ulisipo , Ato* 2. *sc.* 6. “era já *mũito noite*.” *Leão Cron. J.* 1. *c.* 49. **diriamos alias certo : tem dormido *mũita noite* fora** ; por *mũitas* em numero : *mũito noite* ; tarde , depois d’anoitecer.

There are a few other similar singular constructions with plural meaning:

> ***toda a criança tem** o direito à educação* = ***todas as crianças têm** o direito à educação*
>
> *há **tanto animal abandonado** nesta cidade* = *há **tantos animais abandonados** nesta cidade*

Comment: Great answer.  Thank you.  A typo: "in Portugal in Brazil"

Comment: @Centaurus Glad you liked it. I've added a quote from António Morais da Silva (1813) that approves of *muito* + singular countable noun.

Comment: After reading all this a second time, I find it a really curious construction. Someone stugyng Portuguese as a foreign language would have to be told that the construction is correct.  As native speakers, we automatically presume it's correct because we have heard it from an early age.

Answer (score -2):

This is indeed a Brazilian Portuguese way of speaking. Both conjugations are correct, the only difference is the subject of the sentence:

- "Tem ***muito estudante*** que se considera despreparado para o mercado de trabalho"
- "Temos ***muitos estudantes*** inscritos para as vagas de estagiário."
- "Tem ***muito professor*** que nem se preocupa com o aprendizado...."
- "Tem ***muitos professores*** que nunca participaram de uma greve."

These sentences have something called null subject, where the sentence starts with the verb directly. In these cases, we are talking about two different subjects, which are "nós" and "a gente".
Where we see "temos", we can assume that the null subject is "nós".
Otherwise, where we have "tem", we expect the subject "a gente".
Even with this, there are an exception which is the 4th sentence where we have the verb "tem" followed by ***"muitos professores"***, that we should consider a "nós" subject.

As I said above, both structures are correct, given the right context.

This article may give some more insight about the null subject:
["Tem & muito" and "Temos & muitos"](http://www.infopedia.pt/$sujeito)

Comment: -1: If you're claiming some common usage is not correct, you better back it up with arguments/references.

Comment: That information is available at common dictionaries which explain when and how the plural should be used. It is also available at other articles which provide that information. We can assume those examples given by Centaurus have a bad conjugation of the verb .
I can add some more info to my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: @Granvic, yes, please add that info.

Comment: Answer updated with additional info.

Comment: @Granvic The link is completely unrelated to the question at hand. And besides, it's good practice to excerpt relevant parts from the linked page, just in case it goes offline in the future.

Comment: The link I provided may not have the name of what is pretended but I used for a simple reason: in all the four sentences, the subject is omitted, which means that where you've got "Tem", the "A gente" subject is missing. In the case of "Temos", the "Nós" is the missing subject.

Comment: I hope my last update has proper info & explanation so it is clear to everyone.

Comment: The question is not about the null subject. It's about _muito_ + _singular countable noun_

Comment: I understand that, the point I'm trying to explain is that the difference between a *muito + single countable noun* and *muitos + plural countable noun* is mainly the subject. Using "a gente" would point to a *single countable noun* and *muito*, while "nós" would point to a *plural countable noun* and *muitos*.