# Escolha entre {«muito» + singular} e {«muitos» + plural}, e.g. «vi muita coisa» vs. «vi muitas coisas»

Tags: uso-de-palavras, diferenças

Nós podemos usar ***muito + substantivo singular*** ou ***muitos + substantivo plural*** para exprimir mais ou menos a mesma ideia. Por exemplo:

> (a) Muito rapaz se perdeu neste antro de vício.
>
> (b) Muitos rapazes se perderam neste antro de vício.

A validade das frases de tipo (a) foi discutida e espero que demonstrada [nesta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/muito-singular-countable-noun-muitos-plural-countable-noun-are-they-b). A minha pergunta aqui é: **como é que escolhemos entre uma e outra destas formulações?** Será aleatoriamente? São as duas formas absolutamente equivalentes em sentido e tom? Ou existe alguma diferença subtil que nos leve a usar uma forma mais em certas situações e a outra mais noutras? Existe algum estudo sobre este assunto?

Passou-me pela cabeça ao rever estes tipos de frases que tivéssemos mais tendência a usar a forma singular em situações de maior carga emocional. Mas repito, foi só uma coisa que me passou pela cabeça. Para não complicar, foco a pergunta no par *muito + singular* versus *muitos + plural*. Mas se ajudar, podem considerar também dois outro pares similares:

> (c) Tanto rapaz que se perdeu neste antro de vício.
> (d) Tantos rapazes que se perderam neste antro de vício
>
> (e) Todo o rapaz tem a sua pancada.
> (f) Todos os rapazes têm a sua pancada.

Comment: O singular parece dar a ideia que em qualquer lugar que se se vá se percebe a mesma coisa. O plural parece mais específico daquela região, ou mais comum naquele ambiente ou lugar ou em relação as pessoas que fazem tais coisas. Mas acho que não são relações claras e pontuais.

Comment: Sobre _todo_ / _todos_,  o artigo [_Distributive universal quantification and aspect in Brazilian Portuguese_](https://books.google.pt/books/about/Portuguese_Syntax.html?id=ZovKMlTa0YkC&redir_esc=y) diz que _todo_ tem "sensibilidade aspetual": _todo homem ia/*foi para a praia_, _todo homem foi para a praia um dia_, mas _todos os homens foram para a praia_ não tem problema; e que para indicar reciprocidade _todos_ é a única possibilidade: _*todo aluno se odeia_, _todos os alunos se odeiam_. _Todo mundo_ é um caso à parte, como _every one_.

Answer (score 2):

Na minha opinião o que acontece nesses exemplos são entidades contáveis sendo reinterpretadas como não-contáveis – ou ao menos dando mais margem a tal interpretação.

É **contável** tudo aquilo que é descontínuo, que pode ser claramente considerado uma unidade, e que portanto pode ser pluralizado como um conjunto contável de tais unidades. Um carro, por exemplo, é claramente contável. Frente a vários carros, posso distinguir um a um e contá-los. E se eu cortar um carro ao meio, fico sem nenhum carro.

É **não-contável** aquilo que é contínuo, que representa uma massa homogênea que pode ser subdividida em "porções", mas não em indivíduos. Os líquidos são um exemplo bem claro: se eu dividir uma certa quantidade de água em partes menores, cada uma dessas partes continua sendo água. Não é possível contar indivíduos desse tipo de substância, apenas porções. "Duas águas", dependendo do contexto, podem se referir a quantidades ou tipos diferentes de água, ao contrário de "dois carros", que são sempre dois indivíduos claramente quantificados.

Em muitas línguas, incluindo o inglês, essa oposição é fortemente marcada no léxico, ou seja, uma boa parte dos substantivos é claramente contável **ou** não-contável. Essa propriedade do substantivo vai determinar como ele pode ser combinado com quantificadores numa frase. Em inglês, geralmente é contável o que responde a *how many?*, e é não-contável o que responde a *how much*.

Em português essa propriedade é bem menos marcada no léxico e, quem sabe por isso mesmo, sempre foi omitida pelas gramáticas tradicionais. Ao contrário das línguas em que a propriedade determina os quantificadores "permitidos", em português parece que os quantificadores é que irão determinar se um substantivo, em um dado contexto, referencia algo contável ou não contável.

Os seus exemplos falam de algo tipicamente contável (rapazes), porém em quantidade indeterminada. Em "muitos rapazes", o plural fortalece o aspecto contável, mas "muito rapaz" pende para mais indeterminação. Não sei se existe um consenso entre os linguistas sobre esse assunto, mas o meu ponto de vista é que em "muito rapaz" o aspecto individuativo não é tão forte, e "rapaz" pode ser entendido como uma massa de indivíduos.

Comment: Eu não tou muito seguro disto, mas inclino-me mais para a hipótese contrária: de tender a escolher *muitos + plural* mais para um grupo (*estão muitas crianças aqui no parque, hoje*) e *muito + singular* mais para considerar cada indivíduo individualmente (*ainda há muita criança que passa fome*). Pode acontecer o uso não ser bem igual em Portugal e no Brasil.

Comment: @Jacinto A mim parece-me plausível, pelo menos nalguns casos. Compara "Há muito tempo que não via tantas gajas" com "Há muito tempo que não via tanta gaja". No segundo caso, "gaja" parece-me uma entidade mais amorfa, menos individualizada.

Comment: É por aí mesmo que eu penso, @Artefacto. Não é que haja uma interpretação forçada como massa, é uma abertura para essa interpretação. Com aval da sintaxe, já que muito/tanto funcionam com contáveis e não-contáveis – ao contrário do inglês, em que *much* só se combina com não-contáveis, e *many*, com contáveis.

Answer (score 1):

A maior diferença que percebo é que a forma no singular é mais informal que a no plural.

Concordo também com a ideia do André Lyra; no singular parece uma regra geral que não deve mudar, ou que durou muito; no plural, o peso é o mesmo, mas sugere um evento mais pontual, pode ser que a situação já tenha mudado.

"Todo o rapaz tem a sua pancada." -- dá a entender que é da natureza de um rapaz ter uma pancada.

"Todos os rapazes têm a sua pancada." -- não estabelece um regra de causa e efeito, apenas informa que naquele conjunto de rapazes, todos têm suas pancadas.