# É correto dizer ou escrever "todo dia" ao invés de "todos os dias"?

Tags: número-gramatical, concordância

Frequentemente ouço alguém (até mesmo eu) usando a expressão "todo dia" ao invés de "todos os dias", como nos exemplos abaixo copiados da web.

- "... nosso almoço de todo dia."
- "receitas para todo dia"
- "Isso é algo que eu faço todo dia"
- "Eu não sabia que ... podia fazer interurbano todo dia e ...ficar na internet até de madrugada."
- "Eu sofro bullying todo dia."
- "...alguma recreação ao ar livre, mesmo que não fosse todo dia."

É uma forma correta, tanto na língua escrita quanto falada?

Comment: Um exemplo: "Eu programei todo o dia." seria o mesmo que "Eu programei o dia inteiro". No Brasil "todo o dia" é sinônimo de o "dia inteiro" ou "o dia todo" e isso é diferente de "todos os dias" que pode significar os dias da semana. E no Brasil "todo o" é igual "inteiro" e "todo" sem artigo é igual "cada dia". [Veja mais aqui](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/todo-dia-e-todos-os-dias/23627).

Comment: @gato  Nem sempre "todo dia" e "cada dia" são intercambiáveis. A pergunta é sobre "todo dia" com o significado de "todos os dias".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

É corretíssimo. ***Todo dia***—***todo o dia*** em Portugal—é usado com o significado de ‘todos os dias, cada dia’ há séculos. Pelo menos desde o século XIII segundo o dicionário Houaiss (Lisboa, 2002), cujas partes relevantes cito, desenvolvendo algumas abreviaturas; a aceção relevante é a segunda:

> **todo** /ô/ *adjetivo* (sXIII cf. FichIVPM) **1** a que não falta nenhuma parte; inteiro completo, total <*todo o dia foi de chuva*> <*toda a família se reuniu ali*> ■ *pronome indefinido* **2** (século XIII) qualquer, seja qual for; cada <*todo o cidadão tem direitos e deveres*> […] GRAMÁTICA […] b) é de se notar a diferença, especialmente na norma brasileira, entre *todo o* e *todo*, respectivamente, acepções 1 e 2: *todo o dia* ( = *o dia inteiro*) *foi de chuva; todo cidadão* ( = *qualquer cidadão*) *tem direitos e deveres* (mas aqui, tratando-se do plural, é obrigatório o uso do artigo: *todos os cidadãos têm direitos*…); na norma europeia, o artigo é geralmente usado em ambos os casos

Este uso é análogo ao de *muito dia* com o significado ‘muitos dias’—*passei muito dia sem comer*—objeto [desta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/muito-singular-countable-noun-muitos-plural-countable-noun-are-they-b) e [desta outra](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3579/escolha-entre-muito-singular-e-muitos-plural-e-g-vi-muita-coisa?noredirect=1&lq=1) ou ainda ao de *tanto dia* com o significado de ‘tantos dias’. Como já se viu no Houaiss, este uso aplica-se em princípio a qualquer nome contável:

> Todo (o) cidadão tem direitos e deveres.
>
> Todo (o) casal precisa de privacidade.
>
> Toda (a) criança tem direito à educação.

Ao que parece, no português antigo usava-se a expressão indiferentemente com e sem artigo. Ver [este extensíssimo artigo sobre o assunto no Gramaticalhas](http://www.migalhas.com.br/Gramatigalhas/10,MI212188,61044-Todo+ou+Todo+o). Mas parece que o uso sem artigo, distinguindo *todo dia* (‘todos os dias’) e *todo o dia* (‘dia inteiro’), já foi recomendado no século XVI por Damião de Gois. Parece ter sido também a opção de Luís de Camões (*Os Lusíadas*, Canto I, 2ª estrofe, 1572):

> […] Cantado espalharey por toda parte,
> Se a tanto me ajudar o engenho & arte.

Answer (score 0):

Hoje em dia, em Portugal, a expressão «todo o dia» é, ao que sei, usada invariavelmente com o sentido de «o dia inteiro».