# "Em maio há muito ceifão, mas em junho é que se vê quem eles são." Qual a origem e o significado exato desse provérbio português?

Tags: português-europeu, proverbios

Ouvi uma senhora portuguesa, já de certa idade, dizer: "em maio há muito ceifão, mas em Santa Isabel é que se vê quem eles são". Fiz uma busca no Google mas sem nenhum resultado. Encontrei, no entanto, "... **em junho** é que se vê quem eles são".  No contexto da conversa que ouvi, o significado pareceu ser "leva algum tempo para se conhecer a verdade". Pergunto então:

- Qual o **significado** exato do(s) provérbio(s)?
- "...mas em **Santa Isabel** é que se vê...", é o mesmo provérbio que "em **junho** é que se vê"?  Têm o mesmo significado?  **Por que "Santa Isabel"**?
- Conheço **"ceifão"** como sendo um tipo de foice e é essa a definição que encontrei no dicionário.  Porque então "há muito ceifão"?  O correto não seria **"muitos ceifões"**?
- "Em junho é que se vê **quem eles são**" — Eles quem? Os ceifões?

Comment: O dicionário que viste é o Aurélio, certo? Nos que vi, *ceifão* não aparece como ferramenta, apenas como pessoa que ceifa. Mas encontrei numa [Etnografia da Beira](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk00OKzErCDsPMFNiQ0WVva2j1bT84w%3A1612953287305&ei=x7YjYKKLEo-X1fAP0PWg6As&q=%22ceif%C3%A3o+ao+rabo%22&oq=%22ceif%C3%A3o+ao+rabo%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...10714.12996.0.13456.2.2.0.0.0.0.167.328.0j2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.YInja8RrJVQ) um *ceifão* que é tipo de foice. Exemplo único, por oposição aos muitos (que deves imaginar que vi) de *ceifão* pessoa.

Comment: @Jacinto   Não foi o Aurélio.  Foi um dicionário online, mas não me recordo qual.  Procurei agora e não o encontrei.  Posso ter me enganado.

Comment: Você, downvoter, estaria ajudando a melhorar minha pergunta se explicasse o que não lhe agradou.  Se eu recebo um downvote juntamente com o motivo, não serei eu vil e medíocre a ponto de pensar em retaliação.  O ambiente aqui tem que ser esse, o de aceitar críticas construtivas.  Já basta um outro site que frequento onde alguns membros dão seus downvotes de acordo com simpatias ou antipatias pessoais, e não pelo  valor do que foi postado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Também não encontrei a versão com *Santa Isabel*. A versão com *junho* vem em [vários livros de provérbios](https://www.google.com/search?biw=1366&bih=625&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk039E3OIckE7WHkGbEGyAr79Aw1LWQ%3A1612894791126&ei=R9IiYKGaB-Skgweds5iYCg&q=%22em%20maio%20h%C3%A1%20muito%20ceif%C3%A3o%22&oq=%22em%20maio%20h%C3%A1%20muito%20ceif%C3%A3o%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...46055.50319.0.50853.4.3.1.0.0.0.206.421.1j1j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.sCpO5RMgFQU), mas não encontrei explicações nem sequer exemplos de uso. No entanto o que descobri acerca dos vários elementos é coerente com a tua interpretação — “leva tempo para se descobrir a verdade” — mas o texto sugere-me algo mais preciso: é na hora de agir que se vê o que uma pessoa vale. Temos de ir por partes.

***Ceifão*** é o mesmo que *ceifeiro*, ou ’homem que trabalha na [ceifa](https://www.aulete.com.br/ceifar), que colhe o cereal com uma foice’ (ver [Priberam](https://dicionario.priberam.org/ceif%C3%A3o), [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/ceif%C3%A3o) ou, porque não, já que falamos de coisas antigas, o [Moraes Silva de 1789](https://books.google.pt/books?id=4gVdAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA252&lpg=PA252&dq=%22ceif%C3%A3o%20ou%22&source=bl&ots=mxTXHMf_N7&sig=ACfU3U3tinhjgJ6h8tOApUnFCiPDOU-jaw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi2-POLpt3uAhX9UBUIHffBCa8Q6AEwBHoECAUQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ceif%C3%A3o%20ou%22&f=false)). E *muito ceifão* é o mesmo que *muitos ceifões* (ver [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/3154/muito-singular-countable-noun-muitos-plural-countable-noun-are-they-b)).

**Santas Isabéis** há quatro, mas de longe a mais conhecida em Portugal é a [Rainha Santa Isabel de Portugal](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabel_de_Arag%C3%A3o,_Rainha_de_Portugal), padroeira de  Coimbra. Toda a gente em Portugal já ouviu falar dela e do milagre das rosas. Acresce que o dia dela é o 4 de julho, muito próximo de junho, o que permite admitir que “em Santa Isabel” e  “em junho” se refiram à mesma coisa, nomeadamente ao tempo das ceifas, que é por essa altura. Já os dias das outras Santas Isabéis são muito afastados de junho: em novembro ([Isabel mãe de João Batista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_(biblical_figure)) e [Isabel da Hungria](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Isabel_da_Hungria)) e fevereiro ([Isabel de França](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabel_de_Fran%C3%A7a_(1225%E2%80%931269))).

Agora, o ditado diz que “em maio há muito ceifão”, mas **maio não é mês de ceifa em Portugal**: as ceifas são em junho e julho. É assim na região onde cresci (Torres Vedras, a uns 50 km a norte de Lisboa), e a [Revista Lusitana (1927, p. 14-15)](https://archive.org/details/RevistaLusitana26/page/n13/mode/2up?q=%22maio%20sossega%22) diz o mesmo de Portugal em geral:

> O amanho das terras dá que fazer em Abril. Maio sossega, e deixa esperar as colheitas […]
> Em Junho, são as *ceifas* (Sul) com a actividade febril dos *ceifeiros*, as *segas* (Norte) com o *segadores* (*[segar](https://dicionario.priberam.org/segar) = ceifar*).

A [Revista](https://archive.org/details/RevistaLusitana26/page/n13/mode/2up?q=%22maio%20sossega%22) ilustra isto com vários provérbios (que eu não conhecia): “*Em Junho, fouce em punho*” (*[fouce](https://dicionario.priberam.org/fouce) = foice*, ’ferramenta para ceifar’), “*Feno alto e baixo, em Junho é segado*”, ou “*Maio pardo* (chuvoso, nevoado), *Junho claro*, — para aloirar as searas e ter ceifas ou ségas enxutas”. E este [Boletim (1960)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=tn0vAQAAMAAJ&q=ceif%C3%A3o&dq=ceif%C3%A3o&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiH1q67-dzuAhXZXRUIHcRAC-Q4KBDoATADegQIBBAC) regista “Por São João [24 de junho] / Ergue as uvas do chão / E apronta a *roipa* ao ceifão”.

Então **uma interpretação razoável** é: em maio, antes das ceifas, há muitos que se dizem ceifões, que se mostram disponíveis para ceifar, mas quando chega realmente o tempo da ceifa, em junho ou em Santa Isabel (4 de julho), é que se vê quem é que é mesmo ceifão: quem é que realmente quer e sabe ceifar, e aguenta este trabalho muito árduo (esta [*Memória*... de 1811](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gzU7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22ceif%C3%A3o%20anda%22&source=bl&ots=3tH8GHsdxB&sig=ACfU3U24IgroT4Ao3BGDdJxmERBXwCu9iQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEqu7UkOnuAhVFqxoKHee5A7MQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ceif%C3%A3o%20anda%22&f=false) relata que morriam trabalhadores na ceifa por causa da posição curvada e exposição ao sol e calor do verão, “o único trabalho em que o homem morre”). Generalizando, eu posso dizer maravilhas de mim mesmo, e que faço e que aconteço, mas quando chega a hora de agir é que tu vês se eu realmente valho alguma coisa, se sou o que digo ser, se faço como prometi.

Comment: Então "em Santa Isabel" refere-se ao dia de Santa Isabel.  Faz sentido.  "Em maio tem muito ceifão" refere-se a muitos homens plantando, semeando a terra?   E, em junho ou em Santa Isabel estão a colher a safra?   Não é muito pouco tempo para alguma coisa crescer e ser colhida?

Comment: Torres Vedras é conhecida aqui pelos festejos de Carnaval.

Comment: @Centaurus, *ceifão* = *ceifeiro* = homem que ceifa = que colhe trigo ou outro cereal com uma foice (não tem nada que ver com a sementeira). Por isso me parece que a chave do ditado passa por aí: em maio não há ainda cereal maduro para ceifar, em junho/jullho é que já há. A sementeira creio que é em novembro ou dezembro. Torres Vedras é terra de vinho e fruta; a cultura de cereais por lá era marginal; no meu tempo; ainda lá estão as ruínas dos moinhos de vento a atestar uma cultura cerealífera doutros tempos.

Comment: @Centaurus, por "em maio há muito ceifão" eu entendo "em maio, quando ainda não há trabalho de ceifão, há muitos que se mostram prontos a ceifar (quando a ceifa chegar, imagino)" mas em junho é que se vê se eles realmente são bons ceifões. É esta a ideia que eu quis passar na resposta; se calhar preciso de clarificar. Na mesma linha, mas mais sarcástico e pessimista, "muitos oferecem os seus préstimos quando (sabem que) não são necessários; mas quando são, esquivam-se". Em todos estes exemplos, descobre-se a verdade mais tarde, como sugeriste, mas é mais específico.

Comment: Ah, agora entendi.

Comment: @Jacinto pensei em escrever segundo as linhas que seguiste, não o fiz por várias razões. Primeiro, porque elaborar sobre as devoções populares tem sido -em geral- mal recebido aqui no pt.se (por ignorância, secularismo ou sectarismo) e até motivou o aparecimento de *"trolls"*. Depois, o ditado carecia de fontes (é normal) bem podia ser um trocadilho comunista (que pretende ridiculaziar quem lhe atribuir origem na sabedoria popular).

Comment: Por fim, como sabes, o pior indicador do site é o número de repostas por pergunta, mas repara que em geral as respostas possiveis são mal recebidas (com críticas que só procuram defeitos mas por sua vez não acrescentam nada). O que sendo intencional, ou não, leva os interessados a perderem o interesse (repara que no ano passado primeiros posts de utilizadores recem chegados recebiam um número injustificável de votos, enquanto os posts de utilizadores mais assiduos eram sistematicamente desprezados). Em balanço, diz o dito:"assim se vê quem eles são".

Comment: @bad_coder, pois, cada voto é uma decisão individual, e cada votante é soberano; é o que é. A tua resposta ajudou-me, porque fiquei logo a saber que havia várias Santas Isabéis (só conhecia a de Portugal). Mas de resto não achei convincente; por isso não votei. Também não critiquei; tanta coisa a discutir, ficaria um estendal de comentários; teríamos de ir para o chat. Eh pá, eu espero que o pessoal não veja na minha resposta uma elaboração sobre devoções. Conhecer um santo e o seu dia nem implica devoção. Eu sabia da Rainha Santa Isabel de Portugal, mas (lá vai estendal) >>

Comment: >>  nem sabia que ela tinha sido canonizada (nunca tinha pensado nisso, pois tinha de ter sido, se não, não era santa). Nem sabia o dia dela. Mas quando vi "pelo São João, apronta a *roipa* ao ceifão", eu sei que o (dia de) São João é em fins de junho e compreendo implcação,mesmo sem ser devoto.

Comment: Lendo novamente a tua resposta, penso que  "é na hora de agir que se vê o que uma pessoa vale"  é exatamente o que o provérbio diz.

Comment: @Centaurus, ótimo. Faz sentido no contexto do que ouviste à "senhora de certa idade"? A ceifa é, ou foi em tempos, uma boa atividade para ilustrar essa ideia. Também poderíamos dizer, "em agosto há muito vindimador, mas em setembro (que é quando começam as vindimas) é que se vê quem eles são". Mas a ceifa era aparentemente um trabalho especialmente árduo. >>

Comment: >> Diz [esta *Memória* de 1911](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gzU7AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA27&lpg=PA27&dq=%22ceif%C3%A3o+anda%22&source=bl&ots=3tH8GHsdxB&sig=ACfU3U24IgroT4Ao3BGDdJxmERBXwCu9iQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiEqu7UkOnuAhVFqxoKHee5A7MQ6AEwAHoECAEQAg#v=onepage&q=%22ceif%C3%A3o%20anda%22&f=false), que chegavam a morrer ceifões pela posição permanentemente curvada e exposição ao sol e calor do verão; diz o autor que era "o único trabalho em que o homem morre".

Comment: Sim, faz sentido. Acho muito bom alguém desenterrar provérbios antigos de vez em quando para que não se percam de vez. E quando entendemos o que significavam, melhor ainda.

Answer (score 1):

É preciso ver que se perguntarmos ao falantes o significado exacto de um provérbio eles normalmente dão uma resposta muito simples e intuitiva. O uso dos provérbios também é algo local, muitas vezes ligado às culturas e estações do ano num dado micro-clima:

Visto por partes, a primeira é mais fácil de responder:

> “Em maio há muito ceifão

Isto significaria ou a estação das colheitas ou a época antes de começar o clima seco do verão. Em geral, tomando o clima de Portugal como referência, eu consideraria isto o tempo que marca o fim de "roçar erva" ou "ceifar erva" nas hortas e nos campos. É o momento em que deixa de haver chuva sufficiente e a erva começa a secar - passando a paisagem de verde a castanho.

A importância disto prende-se a várias razões, o gado herbívoro é alimentado a erva que é preciso ceifar, portanto os criadores de gado quando a erva seca deixam de ceifar e começam a preparar-se para a colheita do milho e armazenamento de palha e forragens. O mesmo para o agricultor, que neste momento do ano vê a erva no seu máximo crescimento a roubar nutrientes às plantas horticulas e de cultivo - precisa pois de ceifar a erva para consevar as culturas.

> "...mas em Santa Isabel é que se vê...", é o mesmo provérbio que "em junho é que se vê"? Têm o mesmo significado? Porque "Santa Isabel"?

Essecialmente Junho marca o ínicio da época de verão, portanto da época seca. É uma altura em que se pode começar a prever se as colheitas vão ser mais ou menos abundantes. Na prática é o primeiro mês do ano em que as colheitas podem entrar visivelmente em [*"stress hídrico"*](https://sapientia.ualg.pt/handle/10400.1/7487). Dependendo da [região de Portugal](https://observador.pt/2019/08/07/um-quarto-da-populacao-mundial-em-risco-de-ficar-sem-agua-incluindo-regioes-de-portugal/), é um momento que pode ser mais ou menos grave ou reversivel se o tempo mudar.

A referência a Santa Isabel é um bocado mais complicada de análisar. Seria necessário primeiro ver de qual Santa Isabel se está a falar. Pode ser [Santa Isabel mãe de João Baptista](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_(biblical_figure)), Santa Isabel da Húngria, etc...

Não é possivel deduzir unicamente do provérbio a qual santo se refere, até porque se um determinado santo for padroeiro de certa terra poderá referir-se a esse santo e não a outro homónimo.

Uma forma de tentar deduzir qual poderá ser o santo é olharmos para [os dias de festa no calendário litúrgico](https://www.vercalendario.info/pt/evento/liturgia-catolica-ano-calendario-2020.html). No link por acaso não aparece assinalado mas para Santa Isabel mãe de João Baptista será o dia 5 de Novembro - o que é interessante pois é a altura do ano em que as colheitas já estão terminadas e por aí poder dizer-se: *"é que se vê"*, ou seja, **"como correram as colheitas e o ano"**.

> "quem eles são"

Neste caso é uma simples personificação dos destinos e das sortes. "Como as coisas correram e ficaram" personificado "como eles são". (Sim, porque com as pessoas é como com o tempo, só passado um tempo ficamos a saber como as coisas correram e quem eles afinal são.)

**Finalmente**: Não fui capaz de encontrar a referências mas estudos universitários recentes dos próverbios populares ligados a meteorologia indicam que aproximadamente 80% estão correctos na sabedoria que as suas previsões contém.

Ficam um link para leitura (a bibliográfia deste artigo é relevante):

[CORES DO CÉU – METEOROLOGIA POPULARNOS PROVÉRBIOS PORTUGUESES, Zyta Padała.](https://dialnet.unirioja.es/descarga/articulo/5398094.pdf) Romanica Olomucensia 27.2 (2015): 203–211 (ISSN 1803–4136)